# go get github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2 hang on go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.17.0

Tags: go, go-modules, go-fiber

so I want to try fiber on go, but when I try to install the fiber `go get github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2`, the download process always hang on `go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.17.0`. I try to download the repo `compress` manually to test wether the problem is on my internet connection, but it is not, I could clone the `github.com/klauspost/compress` normally

What should I do?

Comment: Not reproducible. Works flawlessly here.

Comment: It might have been hanging on a transitive (indirect) dependency maybe, impossible to say with nothing to go on. When you clone the repo it will only get THAT repo, go get will probably try to get more than that.